# AWS Secret Manager’s Python client-side caching library in a lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

Would it be appropriate to use AWS Secret Manager’s Python client-side caching library in order to cache an API access token within a short-lived lambda function that makes HTTP calls? Our intent would be to reduce the volume of API calls to the Secrets Manager and reduce latency. We plan on rotating the access token by scheduling a CloudWatch Events rule as the token expires every hour and the minimum built-in rotation interval is 1 day.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as it caches across invocations.
https://pypi.org/project/lambda-cache/#SecretsManager

Comment: I foresee an issue where the secret is refreshed in Secrets Manager but still active in the cache. This idea probably isn’t feasible.

Comment: If you need to guarantee to have the latest secret, then something will need to go back to Secrets Manager to check the secret. Alternatively, when updating a secret something could be pushed into a cache to update the secret, but that's not any better than going to Secrets Manager. What is your main driver for reduce the volume of API calls -- is it to save money? It costs `$0.05 per 10,000 API calls.` Perhaps caching for a few minutes would help?

Comment: Cost isn’t a dealbreaker. We haven’t done any testing yet, so I’m thinking about potential lag when hitting Secrets Manager for every request.